# Axis along which coulomb's force acts

Tags: electrostatics

Why does the coulomb's force act along the line joining the two charged particles?

Answer (score 3):

Provided that the Coulomb force exists, its direction along the line, connecting two point charges, could be explained by symmetry, since any other direction would have infinite number of equally likely alternatives and there would be no way to pick one over others.